I'm trying to simulate an output on a LCD display using an ESP32 on Proteus
I have been trying to simulate an output on an LCD display using an ESP32 on 'Proteus 8 Professional'.
But even though I have looked at loads of forums and websites and YouTube videos I can't get mine to give me an output. Only the backlight goes on.
So far I've added a PCF8574 to the circuit, so I can connect the relevant pins from the LCD to the PCF5874:
LCD connected to PCF8574
I also have the SDA and SCL pins ,from the PCF8574, connected to the ESP32:
SDA and SCL pins connected to ESP32 (full circuit)
And I have the LCD grounded to the ESP32's GND pin. The VDD of the LCD is connected to a 5V input.
I got the ESP32 Library from here
All that the LCD shows is this:
LCD Output
I'm using the Arduino IDE to write and Compile the code (which creates the hex file that i load to the ESP32 on Proteus).
The code I have for the ESP32:

#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Initialize the LCD with the I2C address (usually 0x27 or 0x3F)
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  // Initialize the LCD
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight(); // Turn on the backlight
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); // Set cursor to the first column and first row
  lcd.print("Number: 1"); // Display the number 1
  delay(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds
  lcd.clear(); // Clear the display
}

void loop() {
  // Do nothing here
}


Please help me get an output on the LCD screen.

Basic 101 of i2c of I2C communication requires that SDA and SDL to have pull-up resistors.
